# Cómo asegurar acceso Offline de Firebase en Dropdowns - Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, async-await

Tengo un típico formulario donde uno de los campos es una lista desplegable (DropDown), cuyos elementos se obtienen desde la base de datos. El formulario funciona muy bien, sin embargo,cuando se pierde la conexión a Internet, no trabaja la propiedad de Offline Persistence de Firebase y el CircularProgressIndicator se queda activo. Leyendo algunas respuestas como [Using Offline Persistence in Firestore in a Flutter App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549773/using-offline-persistence-in-firestore-in-a-flutter-app), se indica que no se deben manejar awaits, sin embargo no me queda claro cómo lograrlo en este caso:

```
class EstanqueAlimentarPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _EstanqueAlimentarPageState createState() => _EstanqueAlimentarPageState();
}

class _EstanqueAlimentarPageState extends State<EstanqueAlimentarPage> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  AlimentarModel alimentar = new AlimentarModel();
  ///////////////////////////////////////
  AlimentoBloc alimentoBloc = new AlimentoBloc();

  AlimentoModel _alimento = new AlimentoModel();
  List<AlimentoModel> _alimentoList;
  bool _alimentoDisponible = true;

@override
  void dispose() {
    alimentoBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
void initState() {
  _obtenerListaAlimentoUnaVez();
  super.initState();  
}


Future<void> _obtenerListaAlimentoUnaVez() async {
  
  _alimentoList = await alimentoBloc.cargarAlimento(idEmpresa, "existentes"); 

  if (_alimentoList.length > 0) { // Cuando regresa la conexión a Internet, aquí se genera un error BAD STATE
    _alimento = _alimentoList[0];
    _alimentoDisponible = true;
  } else {
    _alimentoDisponible = false;
  }
  _cargando = false;
  setState(() {});
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Form(
      key: formKey, 
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget> [
          _crearTipoAlimento(_alimentoList),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          _crearComentarios(),
        ]
      )
    ),
    _crearBoton('Guardar'),

  }

  Widget _crearTipoAlimento(List<AlimentoModel> lista) {

    return Container(
      decoration: _cajaBlanca,
      child: 
      !_cargando
      ? DropdownButtonFormField<AlimentoModel>(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Nombre del Alimento',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
          prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.boxOpen, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,),
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        value: _alimento,
        items: lista.map((AlimentoModel value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<AlimentoModel>(
            child: Text(value.nombre),
            value: value,
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (_alimentoDisponible) ? (AlimentoModel _alimentoSeleccionado) {
          print(_alimentoSeleccionado.nombre);
          _alimento = _alimentoSeleccionado;
          setState(() {});
        } : null,
        disabledHint: Text('No hay Alimento en Bodega'),
        onSaved: (value) {
          alimentar.idAlimento = _alimento.idAlimento;
          alimentar.nombreAlimento = _alimento.nombreRef; 
        }
      )
      : Center (child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 1.0,))

    );
    
  }


  Widget _crearComentarios() {
    return TextFormField(
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.commentDots, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                labelText: 'Comentarios',
              ),
              onSaved: (value) {
                alimentar.comentarios = value;
              }
             
      ),
    );
    
  }

  Widget _crearBoton(String texto) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0, left:10.0, right:10.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        elevation: 0.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        child: Text(texto, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
        onPressed: (_guardando) ? null : _submit,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _submit() {

    //CODIGO PARA GUARDAR LOS DATOS DE LA FORMA
  }


}
```

El código de cargarAlimento es el siguiente:

En el BLOC:

```
  Future<List<AlimentoModel>> cargarAlimento(String idEmpresa, [String filtro]) async {
    final alimento = await _alimentoProvider.cargarAlimento(idEmpresa, filtro); 
    _alimentoController.sink.add(alimento);
    return alimento;
  }
```

La consulta en el PROVIDER:

```
Future<List<AlimentoModel>> cargarAlimento(String idEmpresa, [String filtro]) async {

    Query resp;
    final List<AlimentoModel> alimento = new List(); 
    resp = db.child('empresas').child(idEmpresa).child('bodega/1').child('alimento')
            .orderByChild('cantidad').startAt(0.000001);
 
  return resp.once().then((snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.value == null) return [];
      if (snapshot.value['error'] != null) return []; 

      snapshot.value.forEach((id, alim){
        final temp = AlimentoModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(alim));
        temp.idAlimento = id;

        alimento.add(temp);
      });
      return alimento;
  });
```

Comment: Para persistir no se debe usar await en modo offline, de otro modo no funcionará, pero para obtener datos, si es necesario el await, el tema es que si estas offline, y nunca antes trajiste datos, entonces saldrá error, pero si ya habías obtenido datos previamente, firestore ya los tiene en caché, entonces puedes obtenerlos sin problemas.

Comment: Gracias Diego. Hice la prueba de traer los datos justo antes (para que se active el caché). Después desconecté el WiFi y volví a entrar al formulario, sin embargo se queda pensando y no trae los datos.

Comment: hmm lo normal es que se quede pensando unos segundos hasta detectar internamente que no tiene internet y luego los trae de caché, te funciona esperando? o ni aún así

Comment: Nop...lo dejo minutos y se queda en el CircleProgressIndicator del código. Cuando vuelvo a activar la conexión, recupera los datos. En otras partes de la aplicación, parece que el caché funciona bien. en el dropdown es donde falla.

Comment: puedes agregar el método `cargarAlimento` a tu pregunta ?

Comment: ok, realizaste alguna configuración en firebase para indicarle que funcionará offline? si es así, que hiciste?

Comment: Nop... entiendo que con el SDK funciona por defecto, no es así?

Answer (score 0):

Estaba revisando tu pregunta con la última actualización, y lo que tu estabas buscando era referente a `Firestore` que también funciona offline, y no necesita ninguna configuración, en tu caso, que usas `Firebase realtime`, es necesario que indiques que debe persistir la data:

```dart
FirebaseDatabase database;
database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
database.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000); // 10MB de cache
```

**edit**

Al parecer hay un issue abierto con el mismo problema https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/885

Mi recomendación es que migres a Firestore por ahora.

Comment: Gracias @diegoveloper. Donde hago eso? En el main o cada que se llama a la Instancia de Firebase?

Comment: en el main es suficiente, solo debe ser llamado una vez

Comment: Nop... lo puse dentro del main, le hice un full restart a la aplicación, entré online al form donde está el DropDown para que se cargara el caché, salí y volví entrar en modo offline y no funciona. Mismo efecto que el anterior con el CircleProgress